# Monacaでバックグラウンド起動する方法(無理やりにでも・・)

Tags: monaca, cordova

MonacaでiOS向けの音楽プレイヤー的なものを制作中です。

アプリを起動後、音楽を再生、
その後に、他のアプリに移動すると音楽が勝手にフェードアウトして消えてしまいます。
どーにかしてバックグラウンドで音楽を流し続けたいです。

http://docs.monaca.mobi/3.5/ja/faq/application/#can-i-develop-applications-that-run-in-the-background

こちらのURLにあるように、バックグラウンドでの開発サポートはされていないという記述があるので大分諦めが入っているのですが、、

http://docs.monaca.mobi/cur/ja/reference/phonegap_34/ja/events/events/

こちらを読むと、Androidだと出来そうなの？みたいな感を受けました。

自作Cordovaプラグインや、設定、カスタマイズで、
なんとかしてMonacaアプリをバックグラウンド起動する方法は無いのでしょうか？

ご協力よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 2):

私も同じようなことをやっているのですが……
音楽再生の箇所だけをiOSのプラグインにして、SwiftまたはObjective-cで書いています。

問題なく動いてはいるのですが、
Monaca上で自作プラグインを使うには上位プランへの加入が必須ということなので、
Monacaで作成させてもらったデータをローカルに持ってきて、残りをXcodeで編集しています。（我ながら手間ですね）

Answer (score 0):

※ 追記です

自作プラグインを作らなくても、
XCodeのプロジェクトでバックグラウンド再生を有効にすれば
CordovaのMediaプラグインでバックグラウンド再生が可能なようです。

・Xcodeのプロジェクト設定の「Capabilities」→「Background Modes」→「Audio and Airplay」にチェックを入れるだけです。

コントロールセンターからの操作に対応するなど、もう少し凝ったものにしたければやはり自作プラグインを書くしか無いと思います。

どちらにしてもMonaca上では出来ませんので、ローカルでcordovaのプロジェクトを作って、そこにMonacaのデータを移すやり方でやってみてはいかがでしょうか。

Comment: 追記は既にある自らの解答を編集する形で行ってください。(※追記で解答が埋もれるため）